# MOD Rewrite is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The other day I was trying to build a friendly URL structure for a website but the mod prepared for that purpuse did not work. I tried it using all the available tools in internet without success

URL: `http://blog.mysite.com/index.php?page=about&lang=en`

I want this url: `http://blog.mysite.com/en/about`

So, what is supposed that should neeed to do?

Comment: I tries 20 times and I'm not an expert in this matter so I request help

Comment: Doesn't Jon Lin's answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes, now the problem is based on the new structure of the friendly url created should I need to modify the structure of the files because for instance: now the images are sought in this path: blog.mysite.com/en/img  but is not the correct url path for the images

Comment: @m4g4bu Try adding a `<base href="/" />` to the header of your pages.